# How do I access the current host's roles in Capistrano?

Tags: capistrano, newrelic, capistrano3

I would like to access the current host/remote machines roles in a `yml` template file when deploying with capistrano.

**What I've tried**

- I've tried experimenting to see if there's a `host` variable available but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

  - `$CAPISTRANO:HOST$` seems to be for older versions of capistrano.

**How could I do something like this pseudocode in a templated yaml file?**

`production:
  app_name: <%= TODO: IF HOST A/b/c -- App 1. If host Z -- app 2 %>`

Comment: Do you want capistrano to deploy on a server (remote machine) after going through a yml file, that contains server and role mapping ?

Comment: @srajappa I'd like to set different values in the YAML file depending on the server the file is being deployed to. So for server A I'd like to set "value 1" and for server B I'd like to set "value 2."

Comment: I am unable to understand, can you illustrate using some example, maybe edit the question a bit ?

Comment: @srajappa I addeda bit more context on how I would like to be able to configure the config file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I have handled a similar problem programatically.

As you may know for each environment there is a .rb file in the config/deploy/ directory.

In our problem, we had a YAML file that had host and role information, viz. below:

`A:
 - web
 - db
 - mongo
B:
 - web
 - app`

To apply this role specific to each host, we iterated over this YAML file (ruby has easy to follow instructions on that) and added a line of code. Here is the psuedocode:

`for host in HOST_LIST_YAML do 
  for role in ROLE_LIST do 
    role :role,  %w{USER@host}
  end 
end`

Here, all the role mappings are applied to the hosts. Similarly, you can write this code on your environment.rb file.

Comment: I think I have the opposite problem: I'd like to take role information (that we've already specified) and apply it to a config file I'm deploying.